# ** (asterisks) characters in lscpu value

Tags: linux, diff

I was working on solving a backlog issue in a company I work where I need to update the validation logic.

Basically the general idea is to compare between two output of a bunch of Linux commands using diff and then decide that an operation PASSes if there are no differences found, and FAILED if otherwise. However, certain differences are allowed depending on condition.

The issue is, someone executed an lscpu command before and the value of BogoMIPS has asterisks(**) in it.

```
  [Missing] CPU MHz:               2393.973
  [Missing] BogoMIPS:              4787.94
  [New]     CPU MHz:               2394.030
  [New]     BogoMIPS:              **4788.06
```

What does those asterisks mean?

Comment: Do you have access to the machine taht gave that output? If so, could you check if /proc/cpuinfo contains the asterisks? AFAICT from `lscpu`'s source, it just parses values from there

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have access to the machine. From what I know, it doesn't always show the two asterisks even on the same machine.

Comment: If you could grab the contents of /proc/cpuinfo when that occurs, that would be good - it seems lscpu just grabs the values from there using [the lookup function](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/lscpu.c#L270), which just searches the word and skips separators and spaces. I have no idea what could cause the values there to contain asterisks, could try finding some kernel reference for that.